# Python RegEx 4 but not 5 number/decimal place pairs

Tags: python, regex, string, decimal-point

I have a Python regular expression pattern:

```
pattern = '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+'
```

For matching the following types of string:

```
1.1.1.1
11.11.11.11
12.34.56.78
```

The problem I have is that the following Strings will result in a match:

```
1.1.1.1.1
11.11.11.11.11
12.34.56.78.90
```

How can I edit the pattern so that only the first set of strings will match?

Comment: Use anchors, `^` and `$`. Check [`^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/vQ5eW8/1)

Comment: @Tushar Can you please elaborate, where do I place the anchors?

Comment: Around the pattern. `pattern = r'^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$'`. Can someone find a good original question to close it with? Looks like I found one :)